# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{4^{\arccos^2 \frac{1}{1 + x^2}} - 1}{\log_4(1 + x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I couldn't evaluate
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{4^{\operatorname{arcos}^2 \left(\frac{1}{1 + x^2}\right)} - 1}{\log_4(1 + x)}$$

The $\operatorname{arcos}$ part is too complicated to differentiate or to Taylor expand. Also, it seems that even with a couple of iterations of de L'Hopital it's not possible to obtain the result (I tried with a CAS). From the graph it is obvious that the limit is $0$.

Comment: Is that $\arccos(\arccos())$ or $\arccos()^2$??

Comment: @amcalde: $\arccos^2 x$ is equal to $\left ( \arccos x \right )^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{4^{\operatorname{arcos}^2 \left(\frac{1}{1 + x^2}\right)} - 1}{\log_4(1 + x)}$$

$$=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{\ln4\arccos^2\frac1{1+x^2}}-1}{\arccos^2\frac1{1+x^2}\ln4}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\arccos^2\frac1{1+x^2}}{(\ln4)^2\ln(1+x)}$$

$$=\frac1{(\ln4)^2}\left(\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\arccos^2\frac1{1+x^2}}x\right)\cdot\frac1{\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}x}$$

$$=\frac1{(\ln4)^2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\arccos^2\frac1{1+x^2}}x=F$$

Let $\arccos\dfrac1{1+x^2}=y\implies x^2=\sec y-1=\dfrac{1-\cos y}{\cos y}$

$$(\ln4)^2 F=\lim_{x\to0}x\cdot\lim_{y\to0}\frac{y^2\cos y}{1-\cos y}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}x\cdot\left(\lim_{y\to0}\frac y{\sin y}\right)^2\lim_{y\to0}\cos y(1+\cos y)$$

$$=0\cdot1\cdot1(1+1)$$

Comment: Very interesting approach, but shouldn't the result be $0$?

Comment: @rubik, I could not find any mistake, can you?

Comment: I plotted all the passages, and it seems that in the second line the denominator in the second limit should be $\ln 4 \ln(1+x)$ instead of $\ln 4 \ln(1+x^2)$

Comment: You can check the plot of the first two lines here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xot0nsddhu. I'm not sure it's completely correct.

Comment: @rubik, Thanks for your pinpointing the mistake

Comment: You're welcome, but please check the plot because even with $\ln(1+x)$ I'm not very sure. With that change, the limit is $0$ though.

Comment: @rubik, Not sure about your area of confusion

Comment: Well I was confused, but now I've done your steps again and I understood it. It's clear now, thank you so much!

Comment: One more thing though. Since $\log_4(1+x) = \frac{\ln(1+x)}{\ln4}$ I believe that at the end of the first part it should be $F = \ln^2 4\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\arccos^2 \frac{1}{1 + x^2}}{x}$. The result obviously doesn't change.

Comment: @rubik, End may not always sanctify the means:) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnomalousCancellation.html

Answer (score 1):

The limit is zero, since $\arccos^2\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is an analytic and even function in a neighbourhood of zero, so:
$$\arccos^2\frac{1}{1+x^2}=O(x^2)$$
and
$$ 4^y = e^{y\log 4}=1+y\log 4+o(y) $$
gives:
$$4^{\arccos^2\frac{1}{1+x^2}} = 1+O(x^2)$$
while:
$$\log_4(1+x) = \frac{x+o(x)}{\log 4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{4^{\arccos(\frac{1}{1+x^2})^2}-1}{\log_4(1+x)}$$
Replace

1)  $\log_4(1+x) \approx x/\log4$

2) $(1+x^2)^{-1} \approx 1-x^2$

3) $\arccos(1-x^2)\approx \sqrt{2}x$

Then
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{4^{\arccos(\frac{1}{1+x^2})^2}-1}{\log_4(1+x)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\log (4)\frac{4^{2x^2}-1}{x}  = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\log (4)\frac{2x^2 \log(4)}{x} =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}2\log(4)^2 x = 0$$